# MySQL Trigger to insert sum of two fields in another one

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I have been using MySQL for quiet some time. But I am totally new to MySQL triggers.

```
Student Table
---------------------------------------------------------
| midterm | final | second_chance | third_chance | total |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   20    |  80   |               |              |  100  |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   15    |  70   |               |              |  85   |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Considering the above table I want trigger that does the following:
After each INSERT OR UPDATE on table the trigger should check if third_chance value is set if so then insert (midterm + third_chance) into total OTHERWISE it should check if second_chance value is set; if second chance is set then insert (second_chance + midterm ) into total; finally if these two (second_chance and third_chance) is not set the insert (midterm + final) into total.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER mytable_bu
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.total = NEW.midterm + 
                   COALESCE(NEW.third_chance, NEW.second_chance, NEW.final);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But the fact that `total` is **always** calculated based on other columns may indicate it shouldn't really be a column in the table at all. Instead, it could be a calculated column in a view:

```
CREATE students_view AS
SELECT s.*, 
       midterm + COALESCE(third_chance, second_chance, final) AS total
FROM   students.s
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this check **`BEFORE INSERT`** and **`BEFORE UPDATE`**, not after.

For example, something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER mytable_bu
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.third_chance IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET NEW.total = NEW.midterm + NEW.third_chance;
   ELSEIF NEW.second_chance IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET NEW.total = NEW.midterm + NEW.second_chance;
   ELSE
      SET NEW.total = NEW.midterm + NEW.final;
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You'd also need a similar **`BEFORE INSERT`** trigger.